# Ограничение на выбор checkbox

Tags: jquery

У меня есть 2 блока с чекбоксами. Нужно, чтобы из блока 'a' можно было отмечать только 5 чекбоксов, а из блока 'b' только 2.

Раньше пользовался таким методом

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $(":checkbox").click(function() { 
    if($(":checked").length>2) this.checked = false; 
  }); 
});
```

Он работает, но действует на все чекбоксы. Помогите доработать код.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему бы не сделать так:

```
$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
    var $block = $(this).parents('[data-max]');
    if ($block.find(':checked').size() > $block.data('max')) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
```

В каждом блоке в `data`-аттрибуте `max` храним максимальное количество чекбоксов, которое можно отметить в этом блоке, при клике сравниваем текущее и максимальное значение.

http://jsfiddle.net/8v43E/

Другой вариант - вешать обработчик `click` не на все чекбоксы страницы, а на блоки, в которые они заключены. Тогда максимальное количество выбранных чекбоксов можно будет не хранить в DOM:

```
function initBlock(selector, max) {
    var $block = $(selector);
    $(selector + ' :checkbox').on('click', function() {
        if ($block.find(':checked').size() > max) {
            this.checked = false;
        }
    });
}

initBlock('#blockA', 5);
initBlock('#blockB', 2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49PTs/

Comment: То что нужно.